# 'null's number value acting differently

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Into Ecma-262, it says number value of null is +0. So when I doing these:

```
var a = null;  //so now a = 0
var b = 0;
var c = 1;
alert(a * c);  //shows '0' as expected
alert(a < c);  //shows 'true' as expected
alert(a > c);  //shows 'false' as expected
alert(a === b);  //shows 'false'
alert(a == b);  //shows 'false' - why ?
```

I know from the Ecma-262 javascript treats +0 and -0 same. Then why it is showing false ?

Comment: You're conflating the numeric *conversion* of `null` with the `==` *comparison* of `null`. The `==` comparison sometimes involves a numeric conversion, and sometimes not. With the `null` value, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

While `null` is *equivalent* to `+0` when used in arithmetic expressions, it doesn't actuall have the *value* `+0`. `null` is `null`, and if you compare it to something that is not `null` then it will be false.

Comment: In that case though string is different object, but it shows true for 15 == "15". Why ?

Comment: Comparing `null` to `undefined` is `true` when using `==`.

Comment: @Arnab Because strings can implicitly be converted to number if needed, much like numbers can be implicitly be converted to strings in some situations.